# How can I use a for loop to sort even numbers from odd numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to take a list of numbers and sort them by whether they are even or odd with a for loop. I can't seem to make it work. I've gotten it to run and give me back ALL the numbers but that's not what I'm looking for. Please help me with this code so that I can actually make it tell me whether a number is even or odd and then omit it if it's even.

```py
def is_odd(num):
    if(num % 2) == 0:
        return(True)
            
    else: return(False)
some_numbers = [91, 88, 38, 103, 199372, 3, 4945, 20098]
for num in list(some_numbers):
    if num == is_odd:
        continue
        print(num)
```

I know I need something after this but currently when I run the code nothing happens which is concerning.

Comment: removing the indent before `print(num)` in last line

Comment: The reason that nothing happens is that this expression: `num == is_odd` is never `True` since `num` seems to be an `int` at all times and `is_odd` is always a function.

Comment: If you really want to sort, you can just use a key with sort/sorted: `sorted(some_numbers, key=lambda n: n % 2)`

Comment: Aside from the `is_odd`/`is_odd()` problem, you're using `%` in a way that will return true for even numbers, not odd numbers.

Comment: By "sort even numbers from odd numbers" do you mean to separate in two groups or you want to _sort_ them (put them in a particular order, like from lower to higher)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
some_numbers = [91, 88, 38, 103, 199372, 3, 4945, 20098]
for num in list(some_numbers):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        print(num)
```

or if you'd like to implement your function:

```
def is_odd(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return False 
    else: 
        return True
        
some_numbers = [91, 88, 38, 103, 199372, 3, 4945, 20098]
for num in list(some_numbers):
    if is_odd(num):
        print(num)
```

You can simplify the function by returning the opposite of its test:

```
def is_odd(num):
  return num % 2 != 0
```

Comment: Whenever you use `if <test>: return False`, `else: return True`, **just return the inverted test:** `return not <test>`. That'll give you a boolean value.

Comment: I agree with Martijn. For example:
def is_odd(num):
  return !(num % 2 == 0)

Comment: @johnkhigginson: Python doesn't have an `!` operator for boolean negation. It's a word, spelled `not`. But in this case, you'd probably want to replace the `==` operator with `!=` instead of using `not num % 2 == 0`. Or, since numbers are truthy if they're non-zero, you could just us `num % 2` as the test.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check if `num` is equal to the function `is_odd`, which will always return `False` as they are not equal.

Here is a modified version of your code that should work:

```
def is_odd(num):
    if(num % 2) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

some_numbers = [91, 88, 38, 103, 199372, 3, 4945, 20098]
for num in some_numbers:
    if not is_odd(num):
        continue
    print(num)
```

Comment: Whenever you use `if <test>: return False`, `else: return True`, **just return the inverted test:** `return not <test>`. That'll give you a boolean value.